# Visual Studio Installer Projects custom file is being used by another process

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, installation

I created a Visual Studio Installer Projects project to install my windows service, but my service uses a custom file that I've created to get configuration, so I have added this file to the installer as a file that must be copied to the destination folder.

So far so good, the file and the installation run fine. But if I try to edit the file (As I will need) it says that is being used by another process, and cant be my service since I've installed manually and didnt run into this problem.

Any suggestions?

Here is how Im opening the file:

```
var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite); 
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fs)) 
{ 
    Data = (ServiceConfiguration)serializer.Deserialize(reader); 
    reader.Close(); 
    log.Info("Configuration file parsed successfully."); 
}
```

EDIT 1:Also I have tried to do the same with installshield and had the same problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Use a program like [Process Monitor](http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB_Article/Using-Process-Monitor-to-Monitor-File-Access) to check it out. But if it's your code causing the problem, we need to see what it is to help you.

Comment: Already did, not only process monitor but several other programs, and all say that the file isnt being used. So I can't find who is blocking.

Comment: Also the same has happened with Installshield. And I have assured in my code that the file doesnt get "stuck".

Comment: So your code must be locking it, and another portion of your code must be trying to access it. Are you using `using` statements for file access? Do you leave any objects disposed?

Comment: Edited with your suggestions. Thank you.